# Trying to apply inlabru:::bru_fill_missing to a SpatialPointsDataFrame to fill in NAs

Tags: r, coordinates, interpolation, sp, missing-data

I'm struggling with a function from the inlabru R package, which could help me fill in the NAs in my data.

According to the helpfile, I need:

```
bru_fill_missing(
  data,
  where,
  values)
```

`data` is a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, which I have - it contains a `data.frame` of 17 climate variables, some of these include NAs.

`where` should be "A matrix, `data.frame`, or `SpatialPoints` or `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, containing the locations of the evaluated values" - I'm guessing this would be the coordinates of the `SpatialPointsDataFrame`?

`values`  is "A vector of values to be filled in where `is.na(values)` is `TRUE`" - so this should be one of the climate variables from the `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.

```
cec2 <- inlabru:::bru_fill_missing(grid2, grid2@coords, grid2$cec)
```

...gives me:

```
Error in inlabru:::bru_fill_missing(grid2, grid2@coords, grid2$cec) : 
  inherits(data, c("SpatialPixelsDataFrame", "SpatialGridDataFrame")) is not TRUE
```

Why is this not working? I seem to be using the right sort of objects:

```
> class(grid2@coords)
[1] "matrix" "array" 
> class(grid2)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
> class(grid2$cec)
[1] "numeric"
> grid2
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 12179 
extent      : 499974.9, 1928094, 8696615, 9781413  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA 
variables   : 17
names       :     gbifID,             Species,    ID, Latitude, Longitude,    costpath,         cec,      Temp10,  thermicity,         tri,        fpar,        lai,        Elev,   soc_0.5cm,         sq3, ... 
min values  :         49, Abelmoschus manihot,     1,  -11.521,       141, 0.158908026, 4.099550837,           0, 12.01840072, 0.160710489, 5.959515748, 1.23322692,           0, 43.46748724,           0, ... 
max values  : 3039118788, Zygogynum argenteum, 13690,  -1.9667,   153.985, 422.5197024, 426.9292313, 101.4610783, 726.4499222, 3756.437675,         254,        254, 4204.876009,  1324.01969, 5.413501295, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation looks wrong. The code is:

```
function (data, where, values, layer = NULL, selector = NULL, 
    batch_size = 500) 
{
    stopifnot(inherits(data, c("SpatialPixelsDataFrame", "SpatialGridDataFrame")))
```

so the first thing it does is stop if the data isn't a SpatialPixels- or SpatialGrid- data frame.

You might be able to coerce your points to a pixels data frame:

```
as(grid2,"SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
```

but non-regular points will fail:

```
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.0146641 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

The `example` code uses a spatial pixels data frame. Suggest you report this on their bug tracker: https://github.com/inlabru-org/inlabru/issues - ok I've done that now: https://github.com/inlabru-org/inlabru/issues/116

Comment: Thank you! - I suppose what they are doing makes sense, as you'd want to interpolate data from a grid covering the entire region (which would therefore have constant cordinate intervals). I think I'd better do that in QGIS though.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation was as intended, stating support for `SpatialPointsDataFrame` input, but the check in the code was wrong, and that has now been fixed in the development version on github. (The support for `SpatialGridDataFrame` was also broken, but has also been fixed.)

The `bru_fill_missing()` function was added mainly to handle very local infilling on domain boundaries. For properly missing data, one should consider doing a proper model of the spatial field instead.